# Pipes output to same command multiple times

Tags: bash

In `bash` is there a *direct* way to pipe the output of a command to another command where there are multiple usages of that output?  In some instances I am going to be able to use `xargs` and replacement strings but suppose I need the second command to deal with the entire piped output, e.g. due to multiple ways of processing that output.

For example (and *this is a deliberately artificial example*), suppose `command1` produces output and I want to calculate a `diff` on the lines of output containing an `a` against those containing a `b`.

I can write:

```
frob=$(mktemp); command1 > $frob; diff <(grep a $frob) <(grep b $frob); rm $frob
```

Is there a more direct way of doing this with a pipe from `command1`?

Comment: Short answer: Not possible without intermediate files.

Comment: @oguzismail That was conclusion I had come to.  Ah, well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary fifo and tee.

```
command1() { printf "%s\n" "a 1" "b 2" "c 3"; }
fifo=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo "$fifo"
trap 'exit 0 ; rm "$fifo"' EXIT
command1 |
tee >(grep a >"$fifo") |
grep b |
diff "$fifo" -
```

I believe you can use bash coproc, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Thank you, although I do not find that a particularly satifying solution.  You're going to need an extra temporary fifo for every additional time the output from command1 needs to be processed.  With the mktemp approach (which I also find unsatisfying) at least only a single file is required.

Answer (score 0):

See if any of these are useful:

```
diff <(command1 | grep a) <(command1 | grep b)
```

or:

```
command1 | { while read line; do diff <(grep a <<< "$line") <(grep b <<< "$line"); done; }
```

or:

```
command1 | { read -d '' -r TEXT; diff <(grep a <<< "$TEXT") <(grep b <<< "$TEXT"); }
```